# Multi-select between parentheses

Tags: vim

Let's say I am looking to have the following highlighted in vim:

[image]

That is, I would like to add the word "END" to the end of each json key, for example:

```
"Accept-END"
"Accept-Encoding-END"
...etc
```

What would be the best way to do this? If it were the same length I could do a visual control-select on down, but here the dictionary key is of varying length, so how would I select or quickly modify all. Here's the text:

```
    get_headers = {
        "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, sdch",
        "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6",
        "Cache-Control" : "max-age=0",
        "Connection" : "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.1 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
    }
```

Comment: @ggorlen sure, updated.

Comment: You could use regex or a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can highlight the text, then use a regex:

```
'<,'>s/\%V" *:/-END&
```

Explanation:

- `'<,'>` applies the following substitution command to the last highlighted text only.
- `s/foo/bar` is the substitution command format replacing pattern `foo` with `bar`.
- `\%V` limits the substitution pattern to match the highlighted region only.
- `" *:` matches the delimiter substrings between keys and values. You could make this more complex if needed.
- `-END&` is the replacement and `&` references the match.

You could also use a [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61882015/6243352), although for 7 lines both solutions might be no faster than typing one line in and using <kbd>.</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

let's say you are on the first line i.e. 'get_headers', to use macro do following:

1. j to go to next line
2. qq to start recording macro at 'q' register
3. ^ to go to first non blank character
4. f" to find the next quotation mark
5. i to get to insert mode
6. -END
7. press ESC let to get to normal mode
8. j to go to next line
9. q to stop recoding macro
10. @q to replay macro or 6@q to replay it 6 times

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro you could use to do that, shown with keypresses here: https://gyazo.com/e02051850977973579adf64147d35edc.

In summary:

- [START] `qa` to start a new macro ("a")
- `f"` to go to the end of the dict key
- `i` then `-END` to insert that suffix.
- `^j` to go back to the start of the line and down a line
- [END] `q` to end the macro
- `6@a` to run that macro 6 times, one for each line below it.